# Displaying image in rails from a different folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How could I display an image from a folder other than images folder under the app/assets?
Suppose I have another folder called im under assests. i.e app/assets/im and I need to display an image under the im folder with the name same as an image under the images folder, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asset Pipeline, all folders (not in the pre-compilation path) will be copied to the `public/assets` folder.

To access the asset, simply do `asset_url("im/image_name.png")`. This will fetch your image.

Comment: I have a image called 'images1.jpeg' under app/assets/imag and also under app/assets/images. How can I display the images1.jpeg under the images folder using image_tag?

Comment: If it is under images folder, then it will be directly accessible with the `image_url` or `image_path` method. Please do `image_path("images1.jpeg")`. This is because `images` also comes under AP.

Comment: This is my code. '<%= image_tag('images1.jpeg', :alt => "logo", :size => "75x75") %>'

Comment: Should I use a image_path inside the image_tag

Comment: you should use `<%= image_tag(image_path('images1.jpeg'), :alt => "logo", :size => "75x75") %>` :)